# Why are my UISearchController delegate methods not being called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller, uisearchbardelegate

I've included the following in my class:

```
@interface DiscoverNew() <UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate>
```

I have my `UISearchController` setup here:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

       [self configureSearchController];

}  

-(void)configureSearchController{

        // Initialize and perform a minimum configuration to the search controller.
        UISearchController *searchController = self.searchController;
        searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = @"Search for friends...";
        searchController.delegate = self;
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
        [searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];

        [searchController.searchBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
        [searchController.searchBar setSearchBarStyle:UISearchBarStyleMinimal];
        searchController.searchBar.tintColor = [GBColor accentGray];
        searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = [GBColor darkGray];
        searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = [GBColor accentGray];
        searchController.searchBar.searchTextPositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(18.0f, 0.0f);

        // Place searchbar above TableView
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar;

}
```

As you can see, I have called `searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;` `searchController` is indeed appearing where it should, and the keyboard is shown when the search bar is tapped, but none of my delegate methods are being called. What's going on?

Comment: Probably because your `searchController` is a local variable with no strong references to it. At the end of `configureSearchController` the `UISearchController` you created gets deallocated.

Comment: @maddy, how would I fix that? Not familiar with strong/weak references and what they do.

Comment: Make `searchController` an instance variable instead of a local variable.

Comment: @maddy I do have `@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchController *searchController;` in my .h file already.

Comment: can you implement searchbar delegate methods?

Comment: @RB1509 I’m away from my project files till tonight. I’ll try your solution ASAP and respond :) your explanation makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a property named `searchController`. But then you create a local variable of the same name in your `configureSearchController` method. So in the end you never set the `searchController` property. As a result, your locally created search controller goes out of scope, has no more references, and gets deallocated.

The fix is to update your code a little.

```
UISearchController *searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
searchController.searchBar.placeholder = @"Search for friends...";
searchController.delegate = self;
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
[searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];

[searchController.searchBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
[searchController.searchBar setSearchBarStyle:UISearchBarStyleMinimal];
searchController.searchBar.tintColor = [GBColor accentGray];
searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = [GBColor darkGray];
searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = [GBColor accentGray];
searchController.searchBar.searchTextPositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(18.0f, 0.0f);

self.searchController = searchController;
```

Comment: Worked perfect. Your explanation helped me understand where I went wrong. Thanks.